# In Colaboratory, CUDA cannot be used for the torch

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, torch

The error message is as follows:

```
RuntimeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-06e96beb03a5> in <module>()
     11
     12 x_test = np.array(test_features)
---> 13 x_test_cuda = torch.tensor(x_test, dtype=torch.float).cuda()
     14 test = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_test_cuda)
     15 test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py in _lazy_init()
    160 class CudaError(RuntimeError):
    161     def __init__(self, code):
--> 162         msg = cudart().cudaGetErrorString(code).decode('utf-8')
    163         super(CudaError, self).__init__('{0} ({1})'.format(msg, code))
    164

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:51
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you have tried so far? What is the exact setup, and what is your relevant code?

Comment: Did you check if you have GPU acceleration enabled?

Comment: yes, I don't open this GPU! Thank you!

Comment: By *"the torch"*, do you mean [PyTorch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyTorch)? The tag wiki for "Torch" says *"Torch is a scientific computing framework for LuaJIT. It is widely used by machine learning researchers around the world."*.

Answer (score 62):

Click on ***Runtime*** and select ***Change runtime type***.

Now in ***Hardware Acceleration***, select ***GPU*** and hit <kbd>Save</kbd>.

Comment: Is the actual spelling *"Change runtime type"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes even after doing the below stop, this error may occur. The reason behind that is that you might be using Colab for long computational processes and it doesn't prefer you using that way.

You can check out the reasons and Google's explanations in this link:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#usage-limits